# Maintain multiple properties files in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a spring boot application and it has multiple property files, one for each environment local, dev, test, performance, production.

Recently we had an incident where someone forgot to put a new property entry into the production property file and the system was down for hours in production.

My question is, are there any better practices on how to maintain properties across multiple property files?

> I am right now thinking of a utility, maybe a unit test that verifies
>   each key exists in each property file and it would fail the build if
>   it does not exist.

I did a few searches but couldn't really find much on it. I understand SO question terms and that I am kind of seeking opinion here. I am more looking to know the better practices on maintaining property files.

Comment: Unit test could be a solution. But then you have to create a test for every property. But if someone forget to write an unit test you will have the same issue.

Comment: @Patrick: I agree with you totally on the maintainability issue. I am not suggesting to write a unit test for each property but a unit test that verifies that all environments local,dev,test,prod etc have same keys. that way, I could atleast verify all keys are in there. thoughts?

Comment: @iMBMT: I dont know how yml file concept helps out here. I understand its a different way to write your property files in. I do get it would be easier to see and read property files and thus spot such human errors.

Answer (score 4):

You should use different properties files for different environments.like

**application-qa.properties** for QA environment

**application-prod.properties** for Production Environment

**application-local.properties** for Local Environment

And then use multiple scripts to start the application for different environments, like each shell script would contain

**mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=qa**

**mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=prod**

**mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=local**

For example *application-local.properties* file is:

spring.profiles.active=local

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost

spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

spring.data.mongodb.database=my_db_name

spring.data.mongodb.username=some_user_name

spring.data.mongodb.password=some_password

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost

spring.rabbitmq.username=guest

spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.rabbitmq.port=5672

rabbitmq.publish=true

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's standard practice followed to separate environment dependent properties and have them injected using spring.profile.active, but the scenario you described seems more to be human error and can occur with any utility, one can have test to verify properties but it introduces maintainability issue. I prefer to manage production related properties using spring cloud config ([here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)) because production properties may contain db credentials and secret keys which may get leaked.

Comment: Totally agree with using spring cloud config for properties anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default properties file. If there is no property in a particular env specific file then it will look into this properties file.

wherever possible while resolving property in spring try providing default value.
For eg.
@Value("${mongodb.url:127.0.0.1}")

Comment: I would personally not use a default value for a property such as a db url, just in case someone forgets to put it in the application-prod.properties and the application keeps on using the default value in production,